# Cannot Perform Aggregate Function

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error when I try and run the code, "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

```
SELECT dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.MANUAL, dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_MDA_TYP_CD, 
    dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.TNG_SYS_NR, 
    COUNT(dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.EMP_TNG_STT_DT) AS CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT,
    dbo.COL_MASTER_COURSE_LIST.Length, 
    COUNT(
        COUNT(dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.EMP_TNG_STT_DT) * (
            CASE WHEN IsNumeric([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH]) = 1 
            THEN [COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH] 
            ELSE 0 
            END
        )
    ) AS Total_Hours
FROM dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES INNER JOIN
    dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2 ON dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group Code] =
        dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.JOB_GRP_CD INNER JOIN
    dbo.COL_MASTER_COURSE_LIST ON dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.TNG_SYS_NR = 
        dbo.COL_MASTER_COURSE_LIST.[GEMS Code] INNER JOIN
    dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE ON dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.TNG_SYS_NR = 
        dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_SYS_NR
GROUP BY dbo.COL_MASTER_COURSE_LIST.Length, dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.MANUAL,
    dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_MDA_TYP_CD, 
    dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.TNG_SYS_NR
```

Comment: You're doing a count on a count * (1 or 0).  That's what it's not liking. You need to do them as independent steps.  Create a subquery that first gets the count * 1 or 0, then do a COUNT on that.  Though why you would count that I don't quite understand, since the count on 0 or count on 1 is the same.  Anyway, that's the core issue.  If you explain the goal/expected outcome in your question, perhaps we can give you a query that suites your needs.

Comment: `COUNT(COUNT(TR.EMP_TNG_STT_DT) * (CASE WHEN IsNumeric([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH]) = 1 THEN [COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH] ELSE 0 END))` can you explain what's the meaning of this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot nest aggregate functions like that. You would have to use a subquery to get the result:

```
select MANUAL,
  TNG_MDA_TYP_CD,
  TNG_SYS_NR,
  CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT,
  Length,
  count(Total_Hours) Total_Hours,
from
(
  SELECT dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.MANUAL, 
    dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_MDA_TYP_CD, 
    dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.TNG_SYS_NR, 
    COUNT(dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.EMP_TNG_STT_DT) AS CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT, 
    dbo.COL_MASTER_COURSE_LIST.Length, 
    COUNT(dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.EMP_TNG_STT_DT) 
            * (CASE WHEN IsNumeric([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH]) = 1 
               THEN [COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH] 
               ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Hours
  FROM dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES 
  INNER JOIN dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2 
    ON dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.[Job Group Code] = dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.JOB_GRP_CD 
  INNER JOIN dbo.COL_MASTER_COURSE_LIST 
    ON dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.TNG_SYS_NR = dbo.COL_MASTER_COURSE_LIST.[GEMS Code] 
  INNER JOIN dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE 
    ON dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.TNG_SYS_NR = dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_SYS_NR
  GROUP BY dbo.COL_MASTER_COURSE_LIST.Length, 
    dbo.COL_TBL_WAGES.MANUAL, 
    dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_MDA_TYP_CD, 
    dbo.COL_2010_TRN_RESULTS2.TNG_SYS_NR
) src
group by MANUAL,
  TNG_MDA_TYP_CD,
  TNG_SYS_NR,
  CountOfEMP_TNG_STT_DT,
  Length
```

Without knowing what your intention is with the query, you might need to replace the outer `count()` with `sum()`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps you are confusing COUNT() with SUM().  COUNT simply counts all non-NULL values.  SUM adds whatever numeric value you supply.

For example, if you peformed COUNT and SUM on the following values you would get the following results.

```
VAL
100
50
25
0

SUM(VAL) = 175
COUNT(VAL) = 4
```

This is what I think you are really shooting for:

```
SUM(
        CASE WHEN IsNumeric([COL_TBL_VCOURSE].[LENGTH]) = 1 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
        END
    ) AS Total_Hours
```